# Nginx Imagejpeg

Tags: php, imagem, nginx

Tenho esse código:

```
function show_image($mime_type, $image_resized) {
    global $quality;
    echo $cache_file = get_cache_file($mime_type);
    switch ($mime_type) {
        case 'jpg':
          imagejpeg($image_resized, $cache_file, $quality);
          //imagejpeg($image_resized);
            break;
        default:
        case 'png':
            imagepng($image_resized, $cache_file, floor($quality * 0.09));
            break;
    }
    echo show_cache_file($mime_type);
}
```

No apache o codigo acima funciona,mostrando a imagem,porém depois que atualizei para o Nginx parou de funcionar.

Mensagem de erro:

> Warning:
>   imagejpeg(): Unable to open './cache/9c1dab025a5849852d4c4be74ee5d1bc.jpg' for writing:

Já verifiquei as permissões,usuário é `www-data`.
Qualquer dica é bem vinda

Comment: Mas tem de dar permissões a `www-data` para poder escrever, 777

Comment: como faço isso ?